# Confusion between "что" and "тот" and "который"

Tags: грамматика

Should you say

> я потеряю то, что любил

or

> я потеряю что, то любил

or

> я потеряю то, которое я любил

?

Should you say

> Я знаю что, о том не знает никто

or

> я знаю то, о чём не знает никто.

?

Comment: Just do a word for word translation. Should one say "i will loose that, what i loved" or "I will loose what, that i loved" ? Should one say "I know what, about that no one knows" or "I know that, about what no one knows" ? Just do a verbatim translation and you have it.

Answer (score 2):

The correct versions are ''я потеряю то, что любил'' and ''я знаю то, о чём не знает никто''. The other versions are grammatically wrong.

In the above correct versions, you can replace ''то'' by ''кое-что'', but the meaning will change:

- With ''тo'', the sentences sound like ''I will lose what I loved'' and ''I know the thing no one else knows.''
- With ''кое-что,'' the same sentences sound like ''I will lose something I loved'' and ''I know something no one else knows.''

Answer (score 2):

"То" can stand for a noun,then you use что as a conjunction.

> Я потеряю то (работу, вещь etc.), что я любил.

"Тo" can stand for a pronoun "that" instead of an adjective,  then you use it with который.

> Я потеряю свое дело, то, которое любил.

The second part.

> Я знаю то, о чем не знает никто.(I know what nobody knows)
>   Я знаю, что о том не знает никто. (I know that nobody knows about that) Mind the comma!

Answer (score 1):

**ТО, ТОТ** — это **указательные местоимения в первой части** сложного предложения.

**ЧТО, О ЧЁМ,  КОТОРЫЙ** — это **союзные слова (местоимения)** **во второй части** сложного предложения.

Союзные слова служат **для связи** двух частей сложного предложения, а также являются **членами** второго предложения.

Образуются **местоименные пары**: то — что, то — о чём, тот — который. Такая связь называется местоименной.

**Правильно:**

Я потеряю то, что любил.

Я потеряю то дело, которое я любил

Я знаю то, о чём не знает никто.

**Сравнить**: *Я знаю, **что** об этом не знает никто.* Здесь нет местоименной пары, а ЧТО — это союз (не местоимение).

ЧТО — **союз** во второй части сложного предложения, служит только для связи двух частей сложного предложения. Такая связь называется **союзной**.

**Союз ЧТО — служебное слово.** Вы сомневаетесь? Тогда я сейчас докажу это, я уберу союз из предложения. *Я знаю: об этом не знает никто*. Получилось бессоюзное предложение. А вот союзное слово убрать не получится.